# styling multiple form select dropdown with one jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I have this js working well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function () { 
       var str = ""; 
       str = $(this).find(":selected").text(); 
       $(".out").text(str); 
    }).trigger('change');
```

The problem is if i have multiple select dropdown (lets say there's no limit) i have to change the class to another so it wont do the same...meaning duplicate the jquery...Is there a way to combine this into one? Here is the Fiddle to see what i mean:

[**LINK to FIDDLE**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9Wt89/153/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3nW3h/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        var str = "";
        str = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        $(this).next(".out").text(str);
        // find the next  element with class out element
    }).trigger('change');
})
```